# GET data from DynamoDB using Node JS SDK

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk-js, aws-sdk-nodejs

I am quite new to work with DynamoDB. I would like to query DynamoDB database for a specific column value and get the data that matches that specific column value using NodeJS sdk

In this case, the DynamoDB is already deployed.

Please suggest how to implement this workflow using Node JS.

Answer (score 0):

most important thing is to create a JSON object containing
the parameters needed to query the table, which in this example includes the **table name**, the
**ExpressionAttributeValues** needed by the query, a **KeyConditionExpression** that uses those
values to define which items the query returns, and the names of attribute values to return for each
item. Call the query method of the **DynamoDB service object**.
here is an example to query dynamodb with nodejs sdk

```
// Load the AWS SDK for Node.js
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
// Set the region 
AWS.config.update({region: 'REGION'});

// Create DynamoDB service object
var b = new AWS.DynamoDB({apiVersion: '2012-08-10'});

var params = {
  ExpressionAttributeValues: {
    ':s': {N: '2'},
    ':e' : {N: '09'},
    ':topic' : {S: 'PHRASE'}
   },
 KeyConditionExpression: 'Season = :s and Episode > :e',
 ProjectionExpression: 'Episode, Title, Subtitle',
 FilterExpression: 'contains (Subtitle, :topic)',
 TableName: 'EPISODES_TABLE'
};

b.query(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) {
    console.log("Error", err);
  } else {

     data.Items.forEach(function(element, index, array) {
     console.log(element.Title.S + " (" + element.Subtitle.S + ")");
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: ya , you already told that , the above example is correct , you just have to change the attribute values,KeyConditionExpression, ProjectionExpression, FilterExpression , TableName with yours table

Comment: and if u need more help , you should provide structure of your dynamodb table and query that you want to perform

Comment: There are lot of Columns in the table. There is a column called createDate and I would like to get the rows matching the createDate column

Comment: Can you please give me a example of sample dynamodb table with the structure, so that I can understand and implement it